# SelectedIndexChanges fires before TextChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling

I have a grid which contains multiple columns/rows with ASP `TextBox` controls. In addition to this, above the grid I have a radio button list which contains years.

The user can enter numbers into the `TextBoxes` and then click an item on the `RadioButton` list to save the information then switch years or click an update button to just save the information and remain viewing the data.

If I click the 'save' button the textchanged event handler fires and I know what rows on my grid had something changed, then I update my DB and then get the data again to display to the user.

If however I click the radiobuttonlist to switch years the `SelectedIndexChanged` event fires but the `TextChanged` event handler does not run because the save and get data runs first, rebinding the grid and eventhandler.

This appears to me to be something to do with the way events run in .net, does anyone know how can I get the textchanged event handler to run first when clicking a radio button list?

I'm using VS2005, .Net 2.5, ASP.Net, C#

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Anyway i can understand that you have problem with the event handlers and how they are called.

I want to know what is the need of calling the textchanged event and SelectedIndexChanged. Even they are not called your data would be get saved perfectly.

Comment: I dont have a problem with how they are called, i have a problem with the order in which they run.
If i click a button the TextChanged event will run before the OnClick of the button event, if i change a radio button list option then the SelectedIndexChanged event will run before the TextChanged event.
I want to know if i can get the TextChanged event to fire first in any situation.

As for data getting saved, im only saving data where i know a value has changed in any input box on the row.